# Iterating a pointer vs character array

Tags: c, pointers

I am trying to understand a bit more about incrementing arrays vs pointers. For example, the following works:

```
char string[] = "Hi";
char * pstring = string;
while(*pstring)
    printf("%c", *pstring++);
```

But if I remove the pointer, it will not:

```
char string[] = "Hi";
while(*string)
    printf("%c", *string++);
```

Why does the first one work? What's the main difference between iteration through a pointer and array?

Comment: The identifier `string` is an unmodifiable char array (`char[]`). You cannot change what it refers to.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin iterating* not incrementing I meant.

Comment: The first one works because `pstring` is a pointer that can be incremented. The second one doesn't because `string` is an array, which is considered to be a constant, and for which dereferencing doesn't even make sense

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's really quite a lot of rationales for why the second one doesn't work. I'm sure you know this, but I'll just reiterate: an array is not a pointer. Arrays are only converted to pointers. This is automatic, and it happens "very often", but arrays and pointers are still different types. In terms of the language, you simply cannot assign to an array (lvalues of array type are not "modifiable lvalues"), and, specifically, the "hidden" `string = string + 1` assignment in `string++` does not work. You can, of course, assign to a pointer variable. For this reason, in the C standard, `++` is defined to work only on numeric ("real") and pointer types, and this means you aren't allowed to give it an array.

In terms of *why* the rules are like this, one train of thought starts by noticing that an array type is only "complete" when it has a size—i.e. if you have a variable of array type, its size is a part of its type. Trying to mutate `string` with arithmetic, as you do here, would require changing the type of `string`, because the size would change, but this is not allowed in C.  (Note that `char string[];` is an invalid declaration because it doesn't specify a size; when you added the initializer you told C to infer the size (`3`) from it.) In the pointer version, `pstring` is a `char*`, and so is `pstring + 1`, so there's no issue. In the array version, you'd need to have `char string[3]` before the loop and `char string[1]` afterwards. Worse, the final size of `string` would depend on the data in it, so there'd be no way to predict it from the language's point of view. Best not open that can of worms, no?

The idea of incrementing `string` also breaks down because, in C, an "array object" is *more* than "a bunch of contiguous elements". When you declare `string`, yes, you create a bunch of `char` objects that are contiguous in memory, but you also "bless" (this is not a technical term, unless you're using Perl :)) that memory into being a `char[3]` object. Probably, in terms of the actual machine, this "blessing" doesn't actually do or mean anything, but, in terms of the abstract machine that C programs run on, there is a difference. Specifically, there is neither an `char[2]` object located at memory address `string + 1` nor an `char[1]` at `string + 2`. Thus, were you to increment `string`, *there would be no array* for `string` to refer to anymore.

I suppose you can boil all this down to the intuition that an array is really just "a bunch of variables". That is, when you declared `char string[3];`, that should feel like you did `char string_0, string_1, string_2;`. This is just like if you had `struct { int x; char y; } test;`—this feels like writing `int test_x; char test_y;`. "Incrementing a group of variables" is quite meaningless, so of course `string++` and `test++` are disallowed. With `string`, you have the option to create a `char *pstring`, such that `pstring = &string_0`, `pstring + 1 = &string_1`, `pstring + 2 = &string_2`, but that doesn't change the fact that doing arithmetic on `string` itself (especially destructively incrementing it) doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my two bits....

**Why does the first one work?**

The pointer "pstring" is a 'variable'. This means that the pointer "pstring" can be re-assigned a new value.

pstring++ is "pstring  = pstring + 1" (allowed).

Other valid pointer operations are:

- Assignment of pointers of the same type.
- Adding or Subtracting a pointer and an integer.
- Subtracting or Comparing two pointers to members of the same array.
- Assigning or Comparing a pointer to zero(NULL).

**What's the main difference between iteration through a pointer and array?**

The name of the array(synonymous with the location of the first element) is **not** a "variable" and will always refer to the same storage.
Though an integer can be added to or subtracted from an array name, re-assigning a new value to an array name is illegal.

string++ is "string  = string + 1" (not allowed).

The difference in coding is extrapolated further in the following:

```
char string[] = "Hi";
int i = 0;
while(*(string+i)){ // or string[i]
  printf("%c", *(string+i));// or string[i]
  i++;
}
```